# Noun Phrase : Action words

Tags: grammar, verbs

The following sentence is copied from the Cambridge Dictionary.

> Our goods sell so well in this country that we have no need to export.

There are two questions of this sentence.

1. The first part of this sentence has noun phrase but it has one words which is not noun or adjective. Is it allowable to use adjective and adverb in the noun phrase.
2. The second part of this sentence that we have no need to export looks to me a present simple tense but the rule says that it should be written as we do not have need to export. Needs some comments on it.

Regards;

Comment: You raised the same question yesterday. Didn't you understand the response you received?

Comment: Sorry biil i did not receive any answer.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Yes, a "noun" phrase is a short, often incomplete sentence which may include any part of speech (but usually must include a noun and a verb).  However I don't think this is actually a noun phrase, but simply a [subordinate clause](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateclause.htm) that follows the pattern "Because of [A], [B] is true."

> Because our goods sell so well in this country, we have no need to export.

A noun phrase would be something like:

> My favorite pastime is [quietly fishing on the lake near my parent's farm].

Everything between the square brackets *acts* as a noun, even though the phrase includes adjectives and adverbs.

2) "We have no need to export" = "We do not need to export".  Using "no" as a [negation is grammatical](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/negation).  It may be a little more complicated so you can stick with the "not" form until you are more familiar with other ways to negate a sentence.

Meanwhile here are some examples:

> It is no secret that they are engaged. (It is not a secret that ...)
>
> I had no sleep last night. (I did not get any sleep ...)
>
> He has no wish to fight with you anymore. (He does not wish ...)